# Converting large integer (uint64+) into hex

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, hex, int128

While importing things into bigquery my hex strings got converted into float. I understand I need to fix the import but I'd like to do a best effort recovery of some of the data.

I'm trying my best to convert them back into hex, however, trying toy examples creates unexpected behaviors.

Ex. Given the following hex value:

```py
hh = 0x6de517a18f003625e7fba9b9dc29b310f2e3026bbeb1997b3ada9de1e3cec8d6
# int: 49706871569187420659586066466638340615522392400360198520171375183123350210774
# float: 4.9706871569187424e+76
```

I'm not sure why the last couple digits goes from 420 to 424 in float

Trying to turn this value into float then back into hex heavily truncates the value

```py
ff = 4.9706871569187424e+76 # same as calling float.fromhex('0x6de517a18f003625e7fba9b9dc29b310f2e3026bbeb1997b3ada9de1e3cec8d6')
int(ff) # 49706871569187423635521182730432496296162592228596139982404260202468916330496
# not sure why getting so many significant figures
hex(int(ff))
# '0x6de517a18f003800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

To me this is unexpected since there is a change in the last non-zero value in hex. (0036 -> 0038)
I'm assuming it has something to do with how mantissa is being represented but was hoping someone on here would have a quick answer rather than going on a deep dive into float implementation in python.

Comment: You need to fix how you import data. You cannot fix this in post-processing - you threw part of your data away.

Comment: `hh` contains 64 hex digits, or 256 bits. Floats are only 64 bits.

Comment: `float.fromhex(hh)` returns `TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation` so `ff = 4.9706871569187424e+76 # same as calling float.fromhex(hh)` claim is false.  `float(hh)` gives that number but as others stated float is 64-bit and the number was truncated.

Comment: In fact the mantissa of a float64 is 53 bits (other bits are sign and exponent) and the last non-zero bit in your `hex(int(ff))` is the 52nd bit which is why it rounds from 36 (0110**1**10 binary) to 0038 (0111**0**00 binary).

Comment: Your design converting a hex string into a float is a terrible idea. Don't do that.

Comment: yes i understand that i need to fix import, the conversion is automatic from google sheets to bigquery. having the first couple characters in hex will be enough to best effort recover original hash

Comment: Recovering 256 bits of data from only the first 53 bits will be a neat trick.  If you already have a list of the uncorrupted data somewhere maybe you can do it, but I'd love to hear details on how you intend to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@mark-tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen) for pointer to 53 bits of float64 and rounding. For my use case of best effort mapping to recover auto conversion issues, the following code will suffice

```py
bb = bin(int(ff))
hex(int(bb[2:53],2)) # 51 bits, see below
# 0x6de517a18f003
```

A bit more explanation:

Hex is represented by 4 bits (2^4 = 16), so when looking at binary positions

- 0..3 - first hex value
- 4..7 - next hex value
- ...
- 48..51 - last complete
- 52..56 - this one is going to be incomplete since we only get 53 bits of precision

Since string is prepended by '0b' we take 2:(2+51) which is how we get to `bb[2:53]`

Comment: Be aware that the rounding that occurred in the int to float conversion may throw off the int that you get back from this process.

Comment: For a concrete example of what I was talking about, try `hh = 0x3fffffffffffff`.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up that edge case, I don't see an easy way to resolve tho...

Comment: I don't see any way to resolve it either, otherwise I would have mentioned it.  Your data has already been irretrievably corrupted by the conversion to float.  I just wanted to alert you to the problem so you might have a plan for dealing with the failures.